# Behavior of an holomorphic function near 0

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem I am trying to solve is set this way:

Let $\Omega=\{z: 0<z<1\}$ the punctured unit disk and $f$ be an holomorphic function  on $\Omega$.

If $$\int_{\Omega} |f(z)|^4 dx dy \lt \infty$$
What can you say about f near $0$?

My thoughts are along this proof but it does not seem to lead me anywhere.

$f(z)$, being regular on $\Omega$, can be expanded into its power series:

Let $f(z)=\sum_{i=1}^na_i z^i$ and write $z=r e^{i\theta}$ where $0 \lt r \lt 1$

\begin{align}
\int_{\Omega} |f(z)|^4 dx dy &= \int_0^1 r dr \int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(r e^{i\theta}\rvert^4 d\theta
\end{align}

Now I would like to use Parseval's identity:
$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \lvert f(r e^{i\theta}\rvert^2 d\theta = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \lvert a_n \rvert^2 r^{2n}$$

Assuming we obtain a condition on the magnitude of the coefficients of the power series of $f$, it seems to me at best we can simply end up concluding that they are bounded and thus f exists near $0$.

Comment: The power series needs to allow negative powers. A priory $z=0$ could be a singular point for $f$.

Comment: How about considering the Laurent series of $f^2$ rather than that of $f$?

Comment: You shouldn't write $0<z<1.$ These are complex numbers.